# Can't insert data into Postgres database with PHP

Tags: php, postgresql

I am creating a simple php api to manage students. The DBMS used is Postgres. While creating the query to insert data into the psql dataabase, i get an error. I'm using Postman to send requests.

Instead of using `SET` i tried using `VALUES` but that still gave me an error saying that the column `name` and `course` exist, but i can't run it in that part of the query.

The line of code:

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO ' . $this->table . ' SET name = :name, course = :course';
```

The error i get:

> ```
> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR: syntax error at or near "SET" LINE 1: INSERT INTO students SET name = $1, course = $2 ^
> ```

Comment: Please show all relevant code.

Comment: I don't think that syntax is correct for PostrgreSQL. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-insert.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert  should use the syntax:

```
'INSERT INTO ' . $this->table . ' ( name, course)  VALUES ( :name,  :course);';
```

Comment: it worked, thanks a lot